# setOnClickListener throws nullPointerException in running time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-lifecycle, android-inflate

I have an Activity which has a fragment. This fragment is changing it's layout depending on what's going on, for instance:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = null;

    switch(nLesson)
    {
        case 1:
            switch(nPage)
            {
                case 0: v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson, container, false);
                break;
                case 1: v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic, container, false);
                break;
                case 2: v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever, container, false);
                    doIt();
                    break;
                case 3: v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.lesso, container, false); break;
            }
        break;
    }
    return v;
}
```

I am changing the nLesson and nPage values as convenied and then using

```
activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .detach(instance)
        .attach(instance)
        .commit();
```

I am refreshing it.

However, in one of those layouts I have some views I want to work with. I am trying to set a onClickListener on one of the views but it always displays a nullPointerException and breaks when running the app (not in compiling time). I tried to set the onClickListener in "`onCreateView`", "`onStart`", "`onResume`", "`onActivityCreated`", etc. Nowhere worked. Any idea?

Thank you, best!

**EDIT**: I am adding some stuff that people asked me.

The layout that breaks is the one called "whatever"; It is a `tablelayout` with 8 `tablerows` and 8 `imagebuttons` on each `tablerow` (that is, a 8x8=64 squares, a chessboard). All the squares are set to null when I try to add the listener on them.

They all are similar to

```
<ImageButton
             android:id="@+id/squareA8"
             android:contentDescription="@string/r8c1"
             android:layout_height="35dp"
             android:layout_width="35dp"
             android:tag="true"/>
```

This is the java code that breaks:

```
public void doIt()
{
    chessHandler = new ChessHandler(cActivity);
    chessHandler.initialize();
}
```

chessHandler is a class from my own, won't post it because it is irrelevant for this case. This is the part of the code interesting:

```
a8 = (ImageButton)activity.findViewById(R.id.squareA8);
a8.setOnClickListener(new on_click(a8, a,8));
```

There are 64 lines as these ones, the `setOnClickListener` breaks because a8 is still set as null after the `findViewById`.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: can you post the layout ?

Comment: Can you post the code where you have the problematic `setOnClickListener()`?

Comment: Most probably that object(on with failed onClickListener ) would be missing from that layout so v.findviewbyid would be null, happened with me many times ...

Comment: @Maaz I'd be happy if that was the case, but it doesn't seem to be! Even the layout is displayed fine, just I can not access the imagebuttons so I can't add the listener, but I see them (with no pic, in fact, as I programmed them on my xml)

Comment: So you're looking up a fragment view from the activity hierarchy. Consider doing the `findViewById()` lookup and click listener setup in the fragment itself, or at least make sure the fragment view is attached to the activity's view hierarchy first (again, using fragment lifecycle callbacks).

Comment: Hm I don't think so @laalto, I am doing it on the fragment itself, this "onCreateView" is the one from my class "public class LessonFragment extends Fragment"

Comment: So why use `activity` for `findViewById()` target and not the fragment view hierarchy (which isn't yet a part of the activity hierarchy)? Usually you inflate a layout in `onCreateView()` - call `findViewById()` on the view you inflated to find its views.

Comment: I agree with @laalto you should either pass view to ChessHandler then call v.findViewId or add fragment view to activity's view hierarchy to access it like you are doing now

Comment: Great, it works. I did it with "activity" because I wasn't aware that I could do it with the view v. Thank you maaz and @laalto , post it as an answer so I can accept it. Really thank you mate! A little offtopic: would be better to do it with the view I just inflated or adding the fragment view to activity's view hierarchy? I am really interested on those usually called good programmer practices.

Comment: A fragment should handle its views itself. Making an activity need to know about a fragment's internals creates unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a8 = (ImageButton)activity.findViewById(R.id.squareA8);
a8.setOnClickListener(new on_click(a8, a,8));
```

In a typical `onCreateView()`, call `findViewById()` on the view you just inflated, not the `activity`. You haven't yet returned the view to the framework and it isn't part of the activity view hierarchy, so any child views cannot be found in the activity.